# Get EC2 instance id that hosts an ECS task for a specific service name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

With AWS SSM plugin, you can login to ECS container with the following:

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-<ec2 instance target id>
sudo su
docker ps
docker exec -it <image id> bash
```

The trick is you need to first find the right ec2 instance id. This can be sort of be done manually via several command line calls. Eg

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster <cluster name>
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster name>
```

But this doesn't give me exactly what I want which is a quick script or oneliner to be able to specify an ECS service name and immediately login to an EC2 instance that is hosting a task for that service.

There obviously may be multiple instances hosting multiple tasks from a service - the first one is ok.

In summary, how can I get the EC2 instance id that hosts a task for a specific service name. Ideally, this instance id can get piped into the `aws ssm` command.

Answer (score 2):

There is a container metadata file that is made available to each container. The file location is automatically placed in an environment variable, `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE`.

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html), you must enable container metadata, because it is not available by default. This can be done by setting `ECS_ENABLE_CONTAINER_METADATA=true` in your ECS EC2 instance's `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` file. (You must restart the ECS agent after updating the file).

You can see the contents of the file in your container by running `cat $ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE`. For example,

```
{
    "Cluster": "default",
    "ContainerInstanceARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:012345678910:container-instance/1f73d099-b914-411c-a9ff-81633b7741dd",
    "TaskARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:012345678910:task/2b88376d-aba3-4950-9ddf-bcb0f388a40c",
    "ContainerID": "98e44444008169587b826b4cd76c6732e5899747e753af1e19a35db64f9e9c32",
    "ContainerName": "metadata",
    "DockerContainerName": "/ecs-metadata-7-metadata-f0edfbd6d09fdef20800",
    "ImageID": "sha256:c24f66af34b4d76558f7743109e2476b6325fcf6cc167c6e1e07cd121a22b341",
    "ImageName": "httpd:2.4",
    "PortMappings": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": 80,
            "HostPort": 80,
            "BindIp": "",
            "Protocol": "tcp"
        }
    ],
    "Networks": [
        {
            "NetworkMode": "bridge",
            "IPv4Addresses": [
                "172.17.0.2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "MetadataFileStatus": "READY"
}
```

With this information, we can make an API call to get the EC2 instance id the container is running on. For the following example, I am assuming that [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and the `aws-cli` are installed in your container. I'm also assuming that you have added an environment variable, `ECS_CLUSTER`, to your [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html), which contains the name of your ECS cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
CONTAINER_ARN=$(cat ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_FILE} | jq -r '.ContainerInstanceARN')

CONTAINER_DESCRIPTION=$(aws ecs describe-container-instances --container-instances ${CONTAINER_ARN} --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --region ${YOUR_REGION})

EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(echo ${CONTAINER_DESCRIPTION} | jq -r '.containerInstances[0].ec2InstanceId')

echo ${EC2_INSTANCE_ID}
```

I am running a similar script in my container. By sure you configure the IAM policy associated with your task's IAM Role so that it has permission to perform the `ecs:DescribeContainerInstances` action.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely interesting to know. However, it seems like it requires logging into a specific container first. The question here is to programmatically find the ec2 container instance among many that is running a particular task.

Comment: @PeterP. Actually, this is intended to be run inside a container as part of a startup script. You don't need to log in, just ensure that your when you build your docker container, your docker command points to a script that wraps your actual service.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out how to do it easily in Ruby with a few systems calls to AWS CLI to output a map of ec2InstanceId to service group

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'json'
cluster = ARGV[0]
container_instances = JSON.parse(`aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster #{cluster} |jq`)["containerInstanceArns"]
container_instances_metadata = JSON.parse(`aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster #{cluster} --container-instances #{container_instances.join(' ')}|jq`)["containerInstances"]
target_map = container_instances_metadata.inject({}){|map, cim| map[cim["containerInstanceArn"]] = cim["ec2InstanceId"]; map}

tasks = JSON.parse(`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster #{cluster} |jq`)["taskArns"]
tasks_metadata = JSON.parse(`aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster #{cluster} --tasks #{tasks.join(' ')} |jq`)["tasks"]

final_map = tasks_metadata.map do |task|
    ec2InstanceId = target_map[task["containerInstanceArn"]]
    [ec2InstanceId, task["group"], task['overrides']]
end
puts final_map.map{|i| i.join(' ')}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved in a simpler way as well, You'r Welcome:

```
CLUSTER=$1
ServiceName=$2
TASKARN=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER --service-name $ServiceName  --output text | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}')
CONTAINER_INSTANCE=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER --tasks $TASKARN | jq -r '.tasks[0].containerInstanceArn')
InstanceId=$(aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster $CLUSTER --container-instances  $CONTAINER_INSTANCE  | jq -r '.containerInstances[0].ec2InstanceId')
InstanceIp=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $InstanceId | jq -r '.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress')
echo $InstanceIp
```